# How to write the right linq where clause?

Tags: linq

I tried to use linq to get storyboard data in code and try following where clause:

```
Where(
   delegate (abc<VisualStateGroup, VisualState> xyz) 
   { return (xyz.state.Name == "PopupOpened");}
  )
```

it gave me error:

> An anonymous method expression cannot
>   be converted to an expression tree

how to write the right where clause for this case?

Comment: `Where(xyz => xyz.state.Name == "PopupOpened")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
Where(xyz => xyz.state.Name == "PopupOpened");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lambda expression:

```
.Where( xyz => xyz.state.Name == "PopupOpened" );
```

If you don't need the operation as an expression tree, you can also write this as an anonymous delegate, but it would be more verbose.

As @itowlson says, if you are using this in a context where an expression tree is expected, you *must* supply a lamda, as only lambdas can be converted into expression trees - anonymous delegates cannot.

Comment: You can't always write it as an anonymous delegate: indeed that appears to be the problem the poster is having.  If his source is IQueryable, he *must* use a lambda rather than an anonymous delegate (because lambdas can be compiled as expressions and delegates can't).

Comment: @itowlson: Indeed, that's something I overlooked when answering the question. I proceeded under the assumption this was a Linq-to-objects question.